# DefaultOAuth2User cannot be cast to class DefaultOidcUser

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, openid-connect, spring-oauth2

I have a simple OIDC Client Spring Boot application in which I used to retrieve the logged in user information as:

```
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (authentication instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken) {
      DefaultOidcUser user = (DefaultOidcUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
      Set<String> roles = authentication.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
              .collect(Collectors.toSet());
      return Optional.of(UserDTO.builder()
          .username(user.getPreferredUsername())
          .firstName(user.getGivenName())
          .lastName(user.getFamilyName())
          .roles(roles)
          .organizationId(getOrganizationIdFromAuthToken((OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication))
          .build());
    } else {
      return Optional.empty();
    }
```

However, after upgrading `spring-security-oauth2-client` to version 5.4.5 there is a `ClassCastException`:

```
class org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.DefaultOAuth2User cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.DefaultOidcUser (org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.DefaultOAuth2User and org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.DefaultOidcUser are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: Which version of `spring-security-oauth2-client` are you updating from?